# How to find records created this month in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Anyone know the best query to find records created THIS month in Rails 3.1?

Comment: You should add more details... like the model definition

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
class Model
  scope :this_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
end
```

you can call it like this:

```
Model.this_month
```

Comment: does this workin sqlite? i was trying to run this in sqlite and it throws 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "<": syntax error: SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE (created_at > '2011-11-01 04:00:00.000000' AND < '2011-12-01 04:59:59.999999')
 from /Users/mrchess/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

Comment: Hmm, try `BETWEEN`: `"created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?"`

Comment: The code in this answer works, but I wish a scope-less answer had been provided instead of or in addition to the scope answer because a scope really isn't necessary to achieve what the OP is asking for and noobs might get confused into thinking that a scope is necessary.

Answer (score 24):

I prefer SQL-less:

```
Model.where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month)
```

or as a scope:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :this_month, -> { where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on if your looking for all records of all models or on a specific model etc...

For a single model you could do:

```
User.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers providing `scope` examples are wrong. Rails uses eager-evaluation on scopes and so `Time.now.beginning_of_month` will always be the start of the month when the scope was initially evaluated. The correct way to use dates in a scope is to pass a lambda to the `scope`.

```rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :this_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
end
```

In Rails 4 scopes must use a callable object such as `Lambda` or `Proc`